# Orbital mean motion expression derivation

Tags: orbital-mechanics, kepler

I'm reading an [article](https://academic.oup.com/mnras/article/458/3/2890/2589321) about tidal forces, and the expression for the mean motion is given by:

$$ n = \sqrt{ \frac{G(M + M^*)}{a^3}}$$

Where $G$ is the gravitational constant, $M$ is the mass of the primary body, $M^*$ is the mass of the perturbing body, and $a$ is the semi-major axis. I know that Kepler laws were used to derive this equation, but I'm not sure exactly how and what are the underlying assumptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer under the assumption of circular orbits of a binary system around their center of mass:

Let $a_1$ and $a_2$ be the radius of the orbit around the center of mass of $M$ and $M^*$ respectively. It follows that: $$a = a_1 + a_2$$
The center of mass satisfies the equation: $$ a_1M  = a_2M^*  $$
From the above two equations we get:
$$ a_2 = a\frac{M}{M + M^*} $$

Newton's second law for body $M^*$ is:
$$ M^* \omega² a_2 = \frac{G M M^*}{a²} $$
Where $\omega$ is the angular velocity of the circular orbit.
Solving for $\omega$ using the expression for $a_2$ we get:

$$ \omega = \sqrt{ \frac{G (M+M^*)}{a^3}}$$

For the orbital mean motion $n$ there should be a factor of $2 \pi$, but I guess it was just omitted

Comment: The standard units of mean motion are radians per unit time,  so no, there isn't a factor of $2\pi$ missing.  Mean motion is just $2\pi$  divided by the orbital period. (Had wrong value, corrected now)

Comment: A useful quantity in two-body calculations is the [reduced mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_mass).